# SpringBoot 2.7.9 Restcontoller is not visible and gives 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Postman is not able to call the rest controller defined in controller package and gets 404 in response even after the springboot application is started and server is up at port 8080.

http://localhost:8080/api/product gives 404 from postman.
i tried 127.0.0.1 and network IP address well but no success.

[image: This is controller defined in separate package and not being called from postman]

[image: Class with main method in separate package]

Comment: i can provide the pom.xml, please let me know.

Comment: In what package is your main? If your Main function is not in the root, then add component scan

Comment: Main class is in package com.hitman.prep.Productservice; and controller is in package com.hitman.prep.controllers;

Comment: Just noticed, better is move every other package under `com.hitman.prep.Productservice`, eg. move `com.hitman.prep.controllers` to `com.hitman.prep.Productservice.controllers;`

Comment: @ Popeye, your comment was helpful, it worked. :)

Comment: also, lowercase the package names

Answer (score 0):

have you changed HTTP request method on postman?

you also can try use one endpoint for each request method for example:

```
@PostMapping(value="/add")
```

and your `POST` request end point should be:

http://localhost:8080/api/product/add